# ¿Cómo puedo instalar la extension de PHP mcrypt en Windows?

Tags: php

He estado buscando pero no he encontrado algo que me ayude.

Lo que he encontrado es para instalarlo en MAC o LINUX, pero lo necesito para windows.

Necesito esta extensión para que mi proyecto de Laravel se ejecute.

Comment: estas usando XAMPP?

Comment: sí, lo estoy usando

Answer (score 2):

Ya he solucionado mi problema, 
les comparto,
Decidí buscar informacion en inglés y encontré esto: 
"Las versiones recientes de XAMPP para Windows ejecutan PHP 7.x que NO son compatibles con mbcrypt. Si tiene un paquete como Laravel que requiere mbcrypt, deberá instalar una versión anterior de XAMPP. O bien, puede ejecutar XAMPP con varias versiones de PHP descargando un paquete de PHP desde Windows.PHP.net, instalándolo en su carpeta XAMPP y configurando php.ini y httpd.conf para usar la versión correcta de PHP para su sitio."

Este es el link de la respuesta -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522384/how-to-install-mcrypt-extension-in-xampp

Decidí tener otra versión de PHP sin desinstalar la que ya tenía y me guié con este vidéo -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtQ-6vkQRRo

Espero les pueda ser de ayuda.